# Does the scope of the group extend to buying new cars and parts?

Tags: discussion

Is the scope of the group restricted to maintenance and repairing or does it also include buying new parts **and cars**? if not...then should it?

I.E.

- [Is a particular car dog-friendly](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7080/are-wagons-hatchbacks-crossover-suv-especially-honda-crosstour-dog-friendly-ca)?
- Should I be concerned if the quote is lower than the lowest value sold based on [Truecar](http://www.truecar.com/prices-new/land-rover/range-rover-pricing/)?
- Is the new Pilot 2014 any different than Pilot 2013?

Comment: It would help if you provided a specific example of such a question.  You should be aware that a lot of pricing information is usually considered "closed-too localized" due to the transient and local nature of the prices.

Answer (score 5):

I'm with Larry.  I don't think your questions would be appropriate.  That is not to say that I am necessarily opposed to new car questions as long as their is a maintenance or repair angle to it.  Such as:

- Is the variable valve/cam timing solenoid on the latest year of
  make/model easy to replace?
- Should I be concerned if one repair quote
  is much lower than the others?
- Did they fix the engine component heat
  treatment problem that the 2013 Pilots were recalled for on the 2014
  Pilot?

Answer (score 3):

I would say no. Based on the FAQ

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories.

[See this answer for more information on shopping questions](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/174/85)

Comment: Looking a bit closer, it seems like these shopping questions are subjective. I'm simply referiing to objective point of view. "Does feature G exist in car X, as oppose to Y? or what is the advantage of having feature G?

Comment: @echad I would still say no, it's not about maintenance or repair. Asking how feature G works might be on topic depending on how it was asked and if it was related to fixing an actual problem that you face